# PHP: loading XML in DOM from Database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, parsing, dom

For some reason this works flawlesly on my out of the box WAMP yet when uploaded to web server it drops the following error:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external
>   entity
>   "/mounted-storage/home155/sub004/sc81961-YHHB/* * * * * *.com/dev/ 
>   2012-10-04 03:15:03 
>   4 2012-10-04 03:25:16
>   2012-09-17 19:25:11
>    3
>   0
>   1
>   1 
>    
>            
>   2012-10-04 04:08:18  "
>
> Filename: models/fuel_model.php
>
> Line Number: 74

It's pointing to the applications root folder.

Code:

```
   function get_pos($id)
    {
        $get = $this->db->query(
                "SELECT * FROM holding WHERE id=1"
            );
        $stream = $get->row_array();

        $addr = 'http://api.eveonline.com/corp/StarbaseDetail.xml.aspx?keyID='.$stream['apiid'].
                '&vCode='.$stream['apikey'] . '&itemID=' . $id;
        $link = new DOMDocument();

      $get_cache = $this->db->query(
          "SELECT * FROM cache_poses WHERE posid=".$id
        );
      $cache = $get_cache->row_array();

      $posted = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
      if(!empty($cache))
      {
        $posted = strtotime($cache['cachedon']);
      }

      $current = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

      $mins = $posted - $current;
      $expiry = $mins % 60;

      if(empty($cache))
      {
        $link->load($addr);
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO cache_poses (data, posid) VALUES (" . $this->db->escape($link->saveXML()) . "," . $id .")");

      } elseif(!empty($cache) && ($expiry >= 360)) {
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM cache_poses WHERE posid=".$id);
        $link->load($addr);
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO cache_poses (data, posid) VALUES (" . $this->db->escape($link->saveXML()) . "," . $id . ")");

      } elseif(!empty($cache) && ($expiry < 360)) {

        $link->load($cache['data']);

      }

        $supply = $link->getElementsByTagName('row');
        $supplies = array();

        foreach ($supply as $fuel) {
            $block = $fuel->attributes;

            $put = $this->db->query('SELECT name FROM items WHERE typeid='.$block->item(0)->nodeValue);
            $lck = $put->row_array();

            $supplies[$lck['name']] = $block->item(1)->nodeValue;
        }

        $info = $this->implode_with_keys($supplies);
        return $info;
    }
```

Comment: Line 74 is: elseif(!empty($cache) && ($expiry < 360)) {

        $link->load($cache['data']);

      }

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the XML? It is referencing a DTD that must be accessible on your local dev machine but not on your live server. If the DTD and the entities it defines are not important to your XML, you can suppress the warning, and likely get a performance increase for not loading an extra resource, by disabling the loading of enternal entities before calling DOMDocument::load().

```
$link->resolveExternals = FALSE;
$link->load($cache['data']);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.resolveexternals

By the way, DOMDocument::load() accepts a file path. If your `$cache['data']` is really a string of XML in the database, you need to use DOMDocument::loadXML().